# MarkLogic - Marker - Github authentication

Tags: github, marker, marklogic

Github authentication is not working for me with Marker from MarkLogic:
http://developer.marklogic.com/code/marker

Everything seems to install ok (I had to change localhost:8100 to mydomain:8100).
I have a Github account but Github authentication doesn't work with Marker.

Here is the output from /var/opt/MarkLogic/Logs/ErrorLog.txt

```
Requested url:/security/authentication/github Content Url:
app-root=[] plugin=[security] controller=[authentication] function=[github]
Caching Roles:security-anon,dls-user
Security is installed - setting application variable
Security is installed or being installed
Authorizing role:security-anon
for:/plugins/security/controllers/authentication.xqy-github
comparing against:/plugins/security/controllers/authentication.xqy-index,/plugins/security/controllers/authentication.xqy-facebook,/plugins/security/controllers/authentication.xqy-github,/plugins/security/controllers/authentication.xqy-_authenticate,/plugins/security/controllers/setup.xqy-install-complete,/plugins/security/controllers/authentication.xqy-logout,/plugins/security/controllers/error.xqy-not-authorized,/application/controllers/welcome.xqy-index,/plugins/marker/controllers/render.xqy-index
Github Authentication
Authentication to https://github.com/login/oauth/authorize?client_id=3h3f34e455b7d6df0f1f&redirect_uri=http%3a//mydomain.com%3a8100/security/authentication/github
```

The browser comes back with page can't be displayed.

Comment: The code in Marker is quite old and not well-maintained.  If what you are looking for is an oauth implementation for github, I would look here: http://developer.marklogic.com/code/oauth2 ; if what you want is Marker, I would consider the project as inspiration, but not something to use other than as bits of a sample implementation.  (Fwiw, even though the page still exists (for historical purposes), MarkLogic has stopped promoting this project on its tools page).

Comment: Thanks again Eric. We were hoping Marker could be used as a viable CMS to build upon. Maybe we can still use bits of it.